# what is the best way to embed a JSF webapp in other?

Tags: html, jsp, jsf, iframe, embed

I need to embed a JSF webapp into a Main page managed by other department.
I've heard suggestions like 'session sharing', iframes (see image below), modal panel/pop up, but I am not sure about security and other concerns, can anyone explain what is the best approach to get this job done in the right way?

thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: And you're not doing the managing? Proceed as normal, tell them to embed your app in an `iframe`.

Comment: after reviewing the servlet-container security configurations I've decided embed the site into an iframe and let the container manage what pages can and cannot be seen.

Comment: If you post that as an answer, more people can see the question is resolved and learn from it.